# get a mongo document based in two different values

Tags: mongodb

I have the following document structure

```
{
            "_id" : "aaa0001",

            "path" : "/some/path",

            "information" : {
                    "name" : "info"
            },
            "colors" : {
                    "colors" : [ 
                        {
                            "key" : "AAAA001",
                            "name" : "White"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "key" : "BBBB002",
                            "name" : "Black"
                        }
                    ]
                }

}
```

the idea is that I have to return the document by the color key. I have two parameters the "path" and the "color", so, I was trying to make something like this

```
db.components.find(
{$and:[
        {"path" : "/some/path"},
        {"colors":{"colors" : {$elemMatch: { "key" : "AAAA001" } } } }
      ]})
```

I'm getting the following message "Script is executed successfully, but there is no results to show".

Can anyone give me some directions regarding this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following query:

```
db.components.find({
    "path": "/some/path",
    "colors.colors.key" : "AAAA001"
})
```

MongoDB expects query document to contain field-value pairs `{ <field>: <value> }`. So, in your example you're querying for a document with `colors` field equal to:

```
{"colors" : {$elemMatch: { "key" : "AAAA001" } } }
```

As for `$and` and `$elemMatch` operators, you don't need them in such a simple query.

For more information read [Query Documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/).

## Update

You can also select only matching subdocument from `colors` array using [Positional Operator $](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/):

```
db.components.find({
    "path": "/some/path",
    "colors.colors.key" : "AAAA001"
}, {
  _id: 0,
  "colors.colors.$": 1
})
```

Though, you won't be able to change your documents structure, thus getting

```
{ "colors" : { "colors" : [ { "key" : "AAAA001", "name" : "White" } ] } }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will take a look of the query documents because now I have to return only the color array. For example
`db.components.find({
    "path": "/some/path",
    "colors.colors.key" : "AAAA001"
})`

should return

`{
  "key" : "AAAA001",
  "name" : "White"
 }`